# Why is RandomizedSearchCV slow?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Trying to do hyperparameter optimization for RandomForestClassifier. It looks like RandomizedSearchCV is 14 times slower than an equivalent set of RandomForestClassifier runs.

The two examples provided below use same training data and same number of folds (6). Example #1 is a classic `RandomForestClassifier()` fit run. Example #2 is a `RandomizedSearchCV()` run on a 1 point random_grid.

Run time: 1min 8s vs. 14min 13s. What am I missing?

### Example 1:

```
%%time
n_fold = 6
time_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=n_fold)
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
cv_scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=time_split, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1)

# CPU times: user 410 ms, sys: 868 ms, total: 1.28 s
# Wall time: 1min 8s
```

### Example 2:

```
%%time
print(random_grid)
n_fold = 6
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 6, scoring = 'roc_auc', cv = n_fold,  verbose=True, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)
rf_random.fit(X, y)
best_random = rf_random.best_estimator_

# {'n_estimators': [200], 'max_features': ['auto'], 'max_depth': [10], 'min_samples_split': [5], 'min_samples_leaf': [2], 'bootstrap': [True]}
# Fitting 6 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 6 fits
# CPU times: user 5min 15s, sys: 4.73 s, total: 5min 20s
# Wall time: 14min 13s
```

Comment: since `n_iter=6`, won't it just sample same point from `random_grid` 6 times?

Comment: 1. Your cross-validator in the first example is `TimeSeriesSplit`, however, in the second
example you only specify the number of folds, which means that `RandomizedSearchCV` will use
`StratifiedKFold` cross-validator by default.


2. In the first example, `RandomForestClassifier` is called with the default parameters,
i.e. with `n_estimators=10` trees to be built. But in the second, as your `random_grid`
dictionary contains `n_estimators=200`, a forest builds 200 trees, which is,
apparently, slower to execute.

Comment: Hi Sanjar, 
yes, you're right: when I put all parameters in the grid equal to default, then the calculation time become similar
Thanks!